# AdapterManager.Update RowNotInTableException

Tags: exception, azure, row, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using a function to delete all data from 9 Tables of my database using typed dataset and `adaptermanager.UpdateAll`.
The update fails with a `DBConcurrencyException`, because one table
throws an `RowNotInTableException`.
All I'm doing is Fill all my tables and then delete the rows. There is no other process working on the database. How can the row get detached? 
Is there a way to get the primary key of the row that is producing the problem?

My Code (shortened):

```
--- 6 other fills before
FillDataTable("parameters");
List<AzureDataSet.parametersRow> parRows = (from p in azureDataSet.parameters where p.ID != "undefined" select p).ToList();
foreach (AzureDataSet.parametersRow item in parRows)
    item.Delete();

 FillDataTable("definitions");
 List<AzureDataSet.definitionsRow> defRows = (from sd in azureDataSet.definitions where sd.hashPK != "undefined" select sd).ToList();
 foreach (AzureDataSet.definitionsRow item in defRows)
     item.Delete();
 --- definitions table produces the error, there is only one more table to fill left

 AzureDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager adapterManager = new AzureDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
 adapterManager.parametersTableAdapter = new AzureDataSetTableAdapters.parametersTableAdapter();
 adapterManager.definitionsTableAdapter = new AzureDataSetTableAdapters.definitionsTableAdapter();
 adapterManager.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate = true; 
 retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
 {
     adapterManager.UpdateAll(azureDataSet);
  });
```

**-- EDIT --**

I tested the delete operation outside of the adapterManager. So I called every `TableAdapter.Update` method separately.
The same table throws the error:

StackTrace:

```
System.Data.DBConcurrencyException
bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
bei System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
bei Apcs.Pcd.NetLib.AzureDataSetTableAdapters.definitionsTableAdapter.Update(AzureDataSet dataSet) in ..\AzureDataSet.Designer.cs:Zeile 21172.
bei ..DeleteAllDatabaseData() in ..:Zeile 2540.
```

-- EDIT 2: SOLVED --

I could solve my problem, but I have no idea what caused the problem. All I did was opening my DataSet.xsd, open the delete command of the table and save the DataSet again. I changed nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem, but I have no idea why the error was thrown. 
 All I did was:
 open DataSet.xsd 
 open delete command of the table 
 save DataSet again.

I changed nothing else!